# How to pass dynamic value in SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass this value `Request.QueryString` in my `asp:SqlDataSource`?

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" 
                    ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:messageexchangeConnectionString %>' 
                    ProviderName='<%$ ConnectionStrings:messageexchangeConnectionString.ProviderName %>' 
                    SelectCommand='SELECT distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_groups ex WHERE (organisation_id = 'Request.QueryString["organisation"]') AND (distribution_address NOT IN (SELECT distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_group_addresses address))'>     
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: That `SelectCommand` appears extremely susceptible to [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:messageexchangeConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT organisation_id,distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_groups ex WHERE (([organisation_id] = @id) AND (distribution_address NOT IN (SELECT distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_group_addresses address))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" QueryStringField="organisation" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) but it return nothing !! i think it is not take the value of organiasation !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2"
         ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:messageexchangeConnectionString %>'
         ProviderName='<%$ ConnectionStrings:messageexchangeConnectionString.ProviderName %>'
         SelectCommand='SELECT distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_groups ex WHERE (organisation_id = '<%# Request.QueryString["organisation"] %> ') AND (distribution_address NOT IN (SELECT distribution_address FROM exchange_distribution_group_addresses address))'>    
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i think  i am getting there but i have this error:
 Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Comment: @Ismail Saifo - "The server tag is not well formed" is raised if the asp.net tags are not complete and donot follow the specified format. I believe that its with the SqlDataSource tag. Check it once

Comment: I did that But when I put : <%# Request.QueryString["mailbox"] %>  
i get the error :(